# How to catch click on QMenuBar

Tags: triggers, qt4, qmenu, qmenubar

I want to catch the click on my QMenuBar that is in QMainWindow, so I have subclassed QMenuBar and I have overrided the mousePressEvent function, but now when I click on menu, the submenus doesn't display them.

An idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end of your `mousePressEvent` function you should pass the event to the base class, which will do its own operations on mouse click:

```
void MyMenu::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // do your stuff
    QMenu::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

[Here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qtcore/eventsandfilters.html) you can read about the Qt Event System.